# Secure authentication between PHP and Obj-c (or whatever)

Tags: php, objective-c, authentication

I'm sitting here and working on a small project, in this case it's between PHP and Obj-c.

What is best practice for secure authentication between these?

something like

```
myhost?do=login&user=my_username&password=my_password
```

feels a bit unsecure since the username and password is posted open.

I guess i could do some SSL for this(?), but does any one have another good example for a good solution?

My thought is that a login sets a auth_key to the user table (MySQL) and if the above GET-variables are correct, it will return userid and this auth key. Then on every thing i do against the PHP, this auth key is updated and returned to the user (obj-c program) and everything that is done on the server is authenticated against this key, this just for not "showing" the password every time and when a key is used, it's useless since it's renewed...

This, however, can't stop anyone for doing this manually since the key is recieved and updated on a login.

Any ideas for making this more secure, or am i just paranoid?

Comment: If I got you right than your 'auth_key' is exactly what a session id is in phps session management. Insisting on using https gets you some level of security. And you should use http post requests for the login, not get requests as you suggested. Post requests are harded to forge and spy on, and the parameters don't show up in any log files. That should be secure enough for most usages. But in the end only you can decide what level of security you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinction between GET and POST doesn't actually matter - both are HTTP requests, and as long as you don't encrypt your data, the plain body of the request can be sniffed.
Of course a login should be as a POST req, but just because it is not idempotent, and may have side-effects [db writing, session start, and so].

You may just want to switch to SSL over HTTPS protocol to be sure your data is safe.

As a [really] minimum protection, you may use [Basic HTTP Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), which encodes login credential in Base64 before sending them - you can do this easily with [RestKit](http://restkit.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use POST for username and password forms along with SSL